# Batch renaming from OOO spreadsheet and CMD

Tags: openoffice.org, batch-rename, file-management

I've got a mess and can't for the life of me figure out how to concatenate this and show it as something that will run. I've done it the way

https://benholland.me/tutorials/2011/11/11/rename-multiple-files-using-excel-in-windows.html

does and can't get it to work with OOO it just keeps using the literal text or errors.

The function =CONCATENATE("ren ",B4, " ", D4) just throws errors ... Any and all help is greatly appreciated.[stuffI've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URgAn.jpg)

Comment: ugh. Closer :/
=CONCATENATE("ren ";B3;" ";D3)

For some reason it's saying file not found

Answer (score 0):

=CONCATENATE("ren ";B3;" ";D3)

^
Worked. I just forgot how to use CMD ... If the files are stored on a different drive you have to use the /d argument ... like CD /d G:\dir\dir\

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, or possibly me, I just got like 3 extra gray hairs.